# Find the Inverse of a Linear Transformation - Tips

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I would like to know some tricks to compute $T^{-1}$.

For example, given $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}_2[x]$ Linear Transformation, such that:

$$T((1,0))=1+x,~~~T((1,1))=1-x$$

Find $T^{-1}(2x)$.

At first, I was trying to compute $T$ itself, which is $T((a,b))=a+(a-2b)x$ and then I was trying to compute $T^{-1}$ with no luck.

After some help, I saw that $T^{-1}(2x)=T^{-1}((1+x)-(1-x))$ and that was very easy to compute.

Unfortunately I didn't notice that at first, so I would like to know how you would approach questions like this one.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well I think you pretty much summed it up in your post. Either you go for brute force: compute a matrix representation of $T$ and invert the matrix so that you have an explicit representation of $T^{-1}$. Or you try to find a more elegant, and potentially considerably simpler way: i) Note that $(1+x)$ and $(1-x)$ form a basis of the polynomials of degree at most 1. ii) Express the point of interest, $2x$, as a linear combination of this basis. iii) conclude using the linearity of $T$.

Comment: Anyway, I suspect that you would anyway have first to prove that $T^{-1}$ exists. If that is the case, then most of the work for either of the above strategies is already done. But again, it depends on if you want to prove the existence of $T^{-1}$ by computing it explicitly, or by looking at the dimension of its image and kernel.

Comment: @Surb Thank you very much for your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you wanted to go along your original method, there's always the brute-force method of finding the matrix of $T$ w.r.t. the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and the basis $\{1,x\}$ of the codomain, then inverting the matrix. So here you'd get $T(a,b)=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 1 & -2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a \\ b\end{bmatrix}$, since this way $\begin{bmatrix}1 & x\end{bmatrix}T(a,b)=a + (a-2b)x$.

Then $T^{-1}$ is given by the matrix $$\frac 1 2\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}$$

with respect to the bases $\{1,x\}$ and the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And indeed,

$$T^{-1}(2x) = \frac 1 2\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 1 & -1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0\\2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}0\\ -1\end{bmatrix}$$

But in general it's worth it to do everything you can to avoid using this approach, since it's nice to avoid having to compute matrix inverses. So, like you found in your case, it's nice to try to see if you can easily write $2x$ as a linear combination of the given values of $T(a,b)$ that you're given before you proceed to the full matrix computation.

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much!